# Creating an array from a script then alert the contents

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've created a script to create a new array called spots, here is the script:

```
main();
function main() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var selectedSwatches = doc.swatches.getSelected();
    var pageNumber = 1;
    var count = 0;
    if (selectedSwatches.length > 0) {
        var text = 'var spots = new Array(\n';
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedSwatches.length; i++) {
            var swatch = selectedSwatches[i]
            var color = swatch.color;
            // Spot
            if (color.typename == "SpotColor") {
                count++;
                text += '"' + color.spot.name + '", ' + "\n";
                color = color.spot.color;
                if (count % 10 == 0)
                    pageNumber++;
            }

        }
        var textend = ');';
        var textArray = text + textend;

        alert(textArray);
    } else {
        alert("No Swatches Selected.");
    }
}
```

This script alerts the following:

```
var spots = new Array(
"Yellow 012 C", 
"Bright Red C", 
);
```

How do I now alert the contents of that array i.e. Yellow 012 C, Bright Red C

I have tried using:

```
alert(spots);
```

But I get the error undefined maybe because the array is created on the fly and its not placed in the script?

UPDATE:

As per the comments, I have edited the script adding:

```
var spots = [];
spots.push(color.spot)
alert(spots);
```

I now get the following error: undefined is not an object

Here's the full script

```
main();
    function main() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var selectedSwatches = doc.swatches.getSelected();
    var pageNumber = 1;
    var count = 0;
    if (selectedSwatches.length > 0) {
        var text = 'var spots = new Array(\n';
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedSwatches.length; i++) {
            var swatch = selectedSwatches[i]
            var color = swatch.color;
            // Spot
            if (color.typename == "SpotColor") {
                count++;
                text += '"' + color.spot.name + '", ' + "\n";
                color = color.spot.color;
                if (count % 10 == 0)
                    pageNumber++;
            }

        }
        var textend = ');';
        var textArray = text + textend;
        var spots = [];
        spots.push(color.spot)
        alert(spots);
    } else {
        alert("No Swatches Selected.");
    }
}
```

Comment: you called main() function before declaring it. try puttng main() below the function block

Comment: @elpmid That doesn't matter, the result will be the same because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: You're creating a string, not an array. You should use `var spots = [];` then use `spots.push(color.spot.name)`. Then `spots` will be an actual array.

Comment: @Reyno oh sorry i forgot. though its best practice to void hoisting

Comment: try `alert(spots.toString());`

Comment: @DominiqueFortin There is no variable named `spots`.

Comment: @elpmid As long as the `main` function declaration is in function scope it can be after it's call because in javascript `function` and `var` are hoisted to function scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
    function main() {
        //var doc = app.activeDocument;
        var selectedSwatches
         = [{"color":{"spot":{"color":"#ff0000","name":"red"},"typename":"SpotColor"}}
           ,{"color":{"spot":{"color":"#000000","name":"black"},"typename":"SpotColor"}}]; 
           // = doc.swatches.getSelected();

        var pageNumber = 1;
        var count = 0;
    
        var spots = [];

        if (selectedSwatches.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedSwatches.length; i++) {
                var swatch = selectedSwatches[i]
                var color = swatch.color;
                // Spot
                if (color.typename == "SpotColor") {
                    count++;
                    spots.push(color.spot.name);
                    color = color.spot.color;
                    if (count % 10 == 0)
                        pageNumber++;
                }
    
            }
            alert(spots.toString());
        } else {
            alert("No Swatches Selected.");
        }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="main()">Main</>
```

Comment: Your code does work but when I replace 'selectedSwatches' with my own I get the error undefined.

Comment: You will have to put a breakpoint and look at the state of `doc` and `doc.swatches`.

Comment: I'm new to Javascript, what do you mean? That above script creates the array from adobe's swatches.

Comment: @Juan-man Look at [breapoint in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints).  The principal is the same for Firefox and Edge.  To get to DevTools, right-click on the page and in the context menu click on `Inspect`.